# ASP.NET 5/EF7 connection string in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.Net 4.5 I could put my connection string in the `web.config` as to take advantage of `web.config transformations` so I could work locally with the development DB and then when I publish it would point to the production DB. I am now working with ASP.Net 5 and EF 7 which seems to use the `config.json` file to store connection strings instead of the `web.config`. With this new way of storing files I can not figure out how to do something like the `web.config transformations` from the past. How can I either setup `config.json` to do this OR configure it so I can do it in the web.config and have EF look there for the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `web.config` transformation syntax is oriented on XML format of data. The new configurations consist of some files in JSON format and one can implement staging scenarios very easy.

First of all ASP.NET supports allows to set destination environment by usage `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable or by setting `Hosting:Environment` in `launchSettings.json` file (see `Properties` folder of your project). The file `launchSettings.json` can be modified in Visual Studio in properties of the project. One should first choose the "Profile"

[image]

and make setting for every profile. Alternatively one can just edit the file `Properties\launchSettings.json` manually.

Some configuration files, like `hosting.json` works automatically using staging. Thus you can set for example different ports and different interface binding by specifying `server.urls` in `hosting.json` and `hosting.Development.json` for example.

To include staging logic in `appsettings.json` one need modify the constructor of `Startup` class in `Startup.cs`. For example:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]);
            })
            .AddDbContext<SM9Context>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SM9ConnectionString"]);
            });
    }
}
```

The above code saves configuration in `Configuration` property and then uses `ConfigureServices` to make injection of `MyContext` and `SM9Context` database contexts. One can for example create main `appsettings.json` file with all productive configuration and create `appsettings.Development.json` file which overrides only *one* (from two `Data:ConnectionString` and `Data:SM9ConnectionString`) connection string:

```json
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=..."
  }
}
```

ASP.NET will combine both files `appsettings.json` and optional `appsettings.Development.json` to create the full set of configuration parameters.

[The article](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) and [the part](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-the-built-in-providers) of documentation describes how one can use the staging in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: How would you access the public `Configuration` property from elsewhere in the application, e.g. in a controller or filter? I would rather make it `private` and available to anything that needs it via the DI container: `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration)`.

Comment: @ProfK: The above code use `static` and `set` property (could be `private set;`) for `Configuration`: `public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }`. Thus, one could use `Startup.Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]` in every part of the code, to read any information from the application configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to pull in configs from different *.json files, the following bases them on environment, or from environment variables;

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

You can also use the ASPNET secret manager.

Each time a config that is accessed, it will override the settings for any config values it has, meaning the variable will reflect whatever it was set to last.

Check out the [docs on Configuration](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html).