# IIS Change WebApi ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, connection-string, entity-framework-core, .net-core

we are using webApi for one of our newest products which is hosted on IIS7.5 and written in ASP.NET5 (.Net Core).

In earlier web-applications it was possible to change the connectionstring in the `web.config` in windows-Explorer and the website running on IIS used the ConnectionString in the `web.config` file.

Is this still possible for modern WebAPIs (I have the ConnectionString insite `appsettings.json`)? I did not find a solution for that inside IIS or File-Explorer and using Environment-Variables do not fit our needs.

We need to switch between several DB-Instances so a very light file-based solution would be very welcome.

PS: We are using EntityFrameworkCore (aka EF7) Database-First as it is a new tool that is on top of our current database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of configuration sources (including JSON, accessed by `AddJsonFile()` in the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`) to read the settings file and then use values read from there to configure EF.

Example code could look like this:

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

For more information see [*Configuration* in ASP.NET Core docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376614/41071).

Comment: Thank you svick! The Configuration `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])` did the trick. I just have to restart IIS-Application (or Pool) after changing the ConnectionString, but that would be more than okay for our testing-environment as we do not change that often :-)